# Unable to connect to internet in Windows Phone 7 Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7-emulator

I am presently working in the Windows Phone 7 using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.But using Phone 7 Emulator ,I am not able to connect to the internet.

Is there any configuration problems,that triggers out this issue.Plz can body help on this

I have attached the issues while launching the windows emulator,and regarding Enabling/Disabling proxy settings,Proxy is disabled by default.I have atttached the screen shot of internet options of Systems,and help me rectify this
[image]

Regards
Rakesh Shankar.P

Comment: ideally it should take your pc net connection. Please check you link by hitting the same link on ie

Comment: I dont know what to check,Can anyone tell me how to proceed next

Comment: Have you tried doing what Prakash has said in his answer? Please try doing that. I hope his answer guides you to your goal.

Comment: I tried accesing the same page in emulator as well as system browser,nones of the pages is accessible in Windows Phone 7 emulator.

Comment: did you try following steps here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff754351%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Comment: HI Milan as suggested in link,I tried Configuring following things 1)Bypassing the Proxy Server for Local Addresses(No sucess) 2) To disable proxy settings (It is like this by default,plz refer pic above) 3)For configure the SOCKS proxy,option of  click Settings is disabled for me 4)For   configure general proxy settings,Since i use LAN,I dont find any settings to be changed

Comment: Is there an issue with your net or GUI? Try updating your GUI settings and did you try the link in the error in the pic you have posted? Apart from all this I dont have any idea of this problem occurring. Please try and let me know. Also try `re-installing` the SDK if all this fails. It might work.

Comment: Hi Milan,On launching the Wp7 emulator,i got this GUI issue .once the emulator gets loaded,I am unable to connect to internet in emulator,and one more thing,I reinstalled the OS again,aind installed VS studio premium and finally windows Phone 7.1 SDK.I am thinking there is nothing to do regarding LAN Settings or proxy server

Comment: Finally i found the problem is because of graphics card,I presently use Graphics card driver WDDM 1.0,but Wp7 emulator requires WDDM 1.1 or later.My present Problem is whether my graphics card(Intel(R) 82945G Express Chipset Family with WDDM 1.0 )can it upgraded to WDDM 1.1.I used the below links for reference 1)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234618/windows-phone-emulator-not-supported-due-to-graphics-processing-unit-configurati 2)http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: great! Add it as an answer and accept it after two days so other people who face the same problem can correct themselves using your effort. :)

Answer (score 0):

What I would check is the proxy settings. More often than not, you might have some problems there. Also, what version of Windows are you using?

Comment: hu Guys,I am not able to understand how to solve this issue,I installed the OS,Still i am not able to connect to internet,There is no proxy settings,I have LAN connection,I dont know how to proceed,any help regarding this will be useful.

Comment: should i be configuring the proxy server for Wp7 emulator to work like Bypassing the Proxy Server for Local Addresses,Configuring the SOCKS Proxy for Windows Phone Emulator,
Configuring General Proxy Settings for Windows Phone Emulator

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue few months back. Desktop IE is working but the Emulator is doesnot have internet connection. I just followed the instructions given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff754351%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This Fixed the problem for me

```
-Open a command prompt on the host computer with Administrator privileges.
-Type ipconfig /renew.
-Restart Windows Phone Emulator.
```

source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff754351(v=vs.105).aspx