# why windows phone 7.1 webBrowser control displaying white screen in emulator?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, xaml, networking, windows-phone-7.1

i m working on windows phone 7.1 and emulator is displaying white screen. i m trying to open http://www.bing.com with webBrowser. no errors in code. I m using internet explorer 9 version, 32bit configuration system, windows 7 operating system, 4 GB ram. why emulator is showing white blank screen? this is the code below in xaml:

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser1" Source="http://www.bing.com" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="9,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="576" Width="441" IsScriptEnabled="True"/>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

> Windows Phone Emulator requires a DirectX 10 or above capable graphics card with a WDDM 1.1 driver.

[WP7 Emulator Browser not displaying anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910194/wp7-emulator-browser-not-displaying-anything)

Comment: i have Directx 11.0 and WDDM 1.0 driver.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you, My OS is Windows 8 + Direct X 11 + WDDM 1.2.

To resolve this problem, please try **set Internet Explorer as your default browsers**. If it still not solve your problem, try to **disable unnecessary add-ons** on Internet Explorer.

After doing this, my location emulator work pretty well.

**Other solution** that may work for you is written here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wptools/thread/cbfb6d94-accd-4416-a25c-9caf52c5c554/

Good luck.